# GitLab variables lookup whereas not asked for

Tags: gitlab-ci, quarkus

I have a quarkus application which needs to read a config property:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "my-property")
String myProperty;
```

That property points to a Gitlab variable :
`my-property=${MY_PROPERTY}` (src/main/resources/application.properties).

But during tests, I need to fix that property: `my-property=FOO` (src/test/resources/application.properties).

When I run tests locally, it works perfectly (the applications uses the value FOO), but the mystery begins when I run tests on my pipeline.

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  image: openjdk:17
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./mvnw compile test
```

and the gitlab variable: [image]. My application shouldn't need the gitlab variable as I overrided the variable in the test configuration file, but the log shows that the output value is BAR and not FOO.

I tried to remove `my-property=...` from both application.properties but the result is the same!

Why and how the application fetches the gitlab variable whereas the config tells not to do so?

Just in case, here is my pom properties:

```
<quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>2.16.4.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [official documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources), Quarkus is trying to match system properties  in the following order (higher ordinal number is higher priority) :

- (400) System properties
- (300) Environment variables
- (295) .env file in the current working directory
- (260) Quarkus Application configuration file in `$PWD/config/application.properties`
- (250) Quarkus Application configuration file application.properties in classpath
- (100) MicroProfile Config configuration file META-INF/microprofile-config.properties in classpath

I believe that Quarkus is trying to find your variable following previous order, and match it at environment step (second one).

As Gitlab provide Environment Variables, your only choice is System properties to bypass matching of environment variables.

## Solution / Workaround

You can provide a System Property that will take precedence by using `-D`
Like this

```bash
    ./mvnw compile test -Dmy-property=myproperty-value
```

You can check this [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference) if you want more informations on how quarkus work with configuration variables.